# How to execute a very large cron in PHP/Linux environment

Tags: php, linux

Hi here's my problem. I need to transfer a large amount of data (hits) from Redis to Mysql everyday. I can't use daily cron, because it'll timeout due to the large amount of data transferred at one go. Anyone got any idea / solution they implemented to this problem?

Comment: I've never heard of `cron` itself timing out.  Could you explain a bit more about what you think is going on?

Answer (score 2):

What will time out? There aren't any timeouts built into cron.

If you're running a PHP script, and that is timing out, then perhaps you need to adjust the timeout settings for PHP scripts?

```
ini_set("max_execution_time", 0);
```

This will disable script timeout for the current executing script (as long as you're on a host which allows you to do so).